# HEAD requests from Linux/Ubuntu boxes

Tags: http-headers, firefox

I don't know if this falls under server fault.  We have HEAD requests disabled on our server.  But we see thousands of HEAD requests, always with the same user agent.  'X11; Linux x86_64 chrome.  It looks like an Ubuntu or other Linux machine.   Have you ever seen a linux browser/Firefox make such a request?  And why would that particular browser be different from the windows equivalent?

It looks like the technique used is HTTP pipelining.

Example user-agent:

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686 on x86_64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0

Comment: I just looked and we've had ~3500 HEAD requests in the last 15 mins from all sorts of user agents...

Answer (score 1):

You should not be disabling `HEAD` — `HEAD` is a compulsory part of HTTP, and a client is allowed to use `HEAD` whenever it desires.

I suspect that your Linux user is using the Polipo proxy, which performs aggressive pipelining and will use the `HEAD` request if the server doesn't properly implement `If-Modified-Since` conditional requests.  Please implement `HEAD` in your server, otherwise you'll be locking out all users of Polipo.

(There are other reasons why a client might decide to use `HEAD`.  For example, some versions of Mozilla/Firefox will query the server using `HEAD` when the user requests a download, so that they can present a confirmation dialog if the download is large.)